# Sort lists in multiple divs with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have multiple list located in separated divs.  As of now each list has its own random ordering, is there a way to sort them all in alpha order WITHOUT moving them our of their div parents?

This is how my markup looks like:

```
<div class="cnf-co-chair">
    <ul>
        <li>H</li>
        <li>B</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="cnf-chair">
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>G</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="cnf-member">
    <ul>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>F</li>
        <li>E</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like the ordering of the items changed to this order instead:

```
<div class="cnf-co-chair">
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="cnf-chair">
    <ul>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="cnf-member">
    <ul>
        <li>F</li>
        <li>G</li>
        <li>H</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this but it only changes the ordering of the first list in the first div:

```
var listToModify = document.querySelector("ul");
var listItemsToShuffle = listToModify.querySelectorAll("li");
for (var i = 0; i < listItemsToShuffle.length - 1; i++) {
    listToModify.appendChild(listItemsToShuffle[i]);
}
```

I am open to use jQuery as long as the location of list items doesn't change in their parent div.

Comment: "*[Can I...] sort them all in alpha order WITHOUT moving them our of their div parents?*" - but your output shows that many of the `<li>` elements *are* being moved from their parents, even thought the number of children per `<div>` is kept the same.

Comment: Yes it sounds weird but that's how the CMS is sorting them out and the request is to only change the ordering of the items not the parents. The answer below solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was:

- Get an HTML collection of the elements
- Convert it to an array of elements
- Shallow copy that array, and sort it
- Loop through the original array and set each element's outer HTML, based on its index, to the outer HTML of the equivalent element in the sorted array.

  - Outer HTML preserves attributes like classes, ID, etc

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li')
const itemArray = [...listItems]
const sortedArray = [...itemArray].sort((a,b)=> {
    return a.textContent < b.textContent ? -1 
      : a.textContent > b.textContent ? 1 
      : 0
  })
  
itemArray.forEach((element, i) => element.outerHTML = sortedArray[i].outerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="cnf-co-chair">
    <ul>
        <li>H</li>
        <li>B</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="cnf-chair">
    <ul>
        <li class="asd">A</li>
        <li>G</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="cnf-member">
    <ul>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>F</li>
        <li>E</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Anytime. Love the username ;P